# .gitignore exclude folder unless it is in parent folder matching pattern

Tags: git, gitignore

I have the following folders:

```
../A/A/bin/
../A/A.source/Bin/
../B/B/bin/
../B/B.source/Bin/
```

Folders that match pattern *.source/Bin/ ("../A/A.source/Bin/" "..B/B.source/Bin/") should not be ignored.

I've tried to achieve this by different ignore rules, but in all cases, it either ignores every bin folder and its content or ignore nothing at all. I've looked through gitignore Documentation, but to no avail.
How can I achieve that?

EDIT: I tried these rules:

```
# everything is ignored
bin
!*.source/bin 

bin/
!*.source/bin/

# everything is allowed
bin/*
!*.source/bin/* 

bin/
!*.source/bin/

bin/*.*
!*.source/bin/*.*
```

Comment: Please add in your question what you tried. You could simply create in each folder that should ignore a `bin` sub-dir a file `.gitignore` with content `bin`.

Comment: I've added rules I tried to use. I try to make rules for gitignore in the root folder because I have 30-40 matching folders, but for clarity sake, I mentioned just 2. So it'd be cumbersome plus there's a chance someone will forget to add a new gitignore when adding a new folder.

Comment: `Bin` directory name appears to be capitalized, but the gitignore file looks up  `bin` in small case. This should be a problem on Linux.

Comment: Forgot to mention it's Windows. Anyway, `[Bb]` does not resolve the issue as well

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As said in the [docs](https://git-scm.com/docs/gitignore#_pattern_format):

> If there is a separator at the beginning or **middle (or both) of the pattern, then the pattern is relative to the directory level of the particular .gitignore file itself**. Otherwise the pattern may also match at any level below the .gitignore level.

(Emphasize mine — *phd*)

This means the pattern `!*.source/bin/` is only applied to the current directory but not subdirectories. To make the pattern works deeper in the directory hierarchy use `**/`. So your patterns should be:

```
bin/
!**/*.source/bin/
```

Comment: I missed that part, now it works as expected. Marked as an answer. Thank you!